# java.lang.NullPointerException: on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
    package com.example.testapp

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView


class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var  EXTRA_TEXT ="fintech"
    private var PRIVATE_MODE = 0
    private val PREF_NAME = "myref"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)
        var passcodeView=findViewById<PasscodeView>(R.id.passcodeView)
        passcodeView.setPasscodeLength(4).listener = object :
            PasscodeView.PasscodeViewListener{
            override fun onSuccess(number: String?) {
                if (sharedPref.getBoolean(PREF_NAME, false)) {
                    val homeIntent = Intent(applicationContext, AfterloginActivity::class.java)
                    homeIntent.putExtra("fintech",number)
                    startActivity(homeIntent)
                    finish()
                } else {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
                    val editor = sharedPref.edit()
                    editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, true)
                    editor.apply()
                }
            }

            override fun onFail() {
                Toast.makeText(this@Main2Activity,"wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this my source code and i get this error:

```
 Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 11939
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView.setPasscodeLength(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView.setPasscodeLength(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testapp.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.kt:46)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
04-02 14:39:57.454 11939-11939/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11939 SIG: 9
```

if i put "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)" below oncreate its work but i want to make it onetime login only so i put it under and then i got this error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView.setPasscodeLength(int)' on a null object reference"
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused by this line:

```
var passcodeView=findViewById<PasscodeView>(R.id.passcodeView)
```

You are trying to find a view when you have not setContentView for the activity.

Comment: i set the contentView under the passcodeview
 else
                   ` setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)//here
                    val editor = sharedPref.edit()
                    editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, true)
                    editor.apply()
                }`
@AmbroseBako

Answer (score 0):

If you don't call `setContentView()` all calls to `findViewById()` will return `null`. `passcodeView` being `null` is the reason for your `NullPointerException`.

There is no way to start the `AfterloginActivity` before `setContentView()` because you rely on `passCodeView` to add something to the Intent when you do `homeIntent.putExtra("fintech",number)`.

Comment: hmmm i follow this tutorial
https://blog.mindorks.com/android-shared-preferences-in-kotlin
in here setContentView() is call in else

Comment: in the tutorial they do not call `findViewById` before `setContentView`. You can do it like in the tutorial ony if you don't need to pass the `number` to `AfterloginActivity`

Comment: and my order is im calling main2Activity first than it will pop up afterLoginActivity
after close the app afterLoginActivity pop up and main2Activity is no showing again

Comment: i need to pass it because i make a app with pin code in the first verification after that use the pin code for login

Comment: then you need to call `setContentView` before `var passcodeView=findViewById<PasscodeView>(R.id.passcodeView)`

Comment: i Need to do is 
Register pin -> Input pin-> home after that
inputpin -> Home